# How do I associate a user foreign key in my Ruby on Rails seed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a 'baby coder' and I am creating a new rails app and I would like to add some seeded data. The app will display different hairstyles belonging to a user meaning that each hairstyle needs a user_id. In my seed file I have created Users and Hairstyles however when I run rails:dbseed in the console it gives me the error:

```
"NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
Did you mean?  users"
```

When I run rails c I see that users are created but my hairstyles aren't. Please can someone help me and explain why this is? Thank you

SEED FILE:

```
Hairstyle.destroy_all

User.destroy_all

users = [
  {
    first_name: 'test',
    last_name: 'Inniss',
    email: 'angela@hair.com',
    password: '123456' 
  },   
  { 
    first_name: 'test2',
    last_name: 'Clarke',
    email: 'aaron@hair.com',
    password: '123456'
  }
]

User.create!(users)

user.save

hairstyles = [
  {
    name: 'Single Braids',
    description: 'Really easy to maintain',
    category: 'Braids',
    video_url: 'www.google.com',
    photo_url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533233336213-b3a32825c689?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80',
    user_id: User.first
  },
  {
    name: 'Crochets',
    description: 'Protective style',
    category: 'Braids',
    video_url: 'www.google.com',
    photo_url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533233336213-b3a32825c689?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80',
    user_id: User.first
  }
]

Hairstyle.create!(hairstyles)
```

Comment: So, you're creating many users. Which of those should `user` from `user.save` refer to? It's redundant anyway, `create!` either creates users or not. There are no pending changes in any of those users.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line

```
user.save
```

It doesn't make sense, you don't need it.

Comment: Hello @spickermann I have removed user.save now and I don't have any errors, which is great however when I type "rails c" into the console and then Hairstyle.all I see an empty array [ ]. Should I not see the 2 hairstyles that I created in my Seed?  Thanks in advance

Comment: @AngelaInniss and the users are there?

Comment: Hello @Ursus Yes the users are there which is strange. I keep running rails db:seed and the users are wiped and created each time. Could it be something to do with my Model?

Comment: One error is that you're assigning a user, the entire object, to `user_id`. Either `user_id: User.first.id` or `user: User.first`.

Comment: Hello @ursus I tried both and it does not work still. I have users and no hairstyles when I type rails c, Hairstyle.all. It's so strange, please let me know if you would like to see any other files/ have any more ideas. I am quite stuck at this point :S

Comment: Then there's something else but we should see model and migration for hairstyle.

Comment: Otherwise you should try to see the errors active record returns. Something like `hairstyles.each do |h| hairstyle = Hairstyle.new(h); unless hairstyle.save then puts hairstyle.errors.inspect end`

Comment: I just added the line of code you wrote above and did rails c Hairstyle.all and it returned something :O. Do you mind explaining why I had to iterate through the hairstyles and create a new one on each iteration? Why did my seed not work the way I had it originally? Thank you!